# HTTP 503 error after first deploy

Tags: dotcloud, cloudcontrol

After my first deploy on Next dotCloud I saw a 503 error when visiting the site. Haven't found anything in the logs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that no `web container` was running.

The solution is to call

```
 $ dcapp <app name>/default deploy --container 1
```

Comment: yes, you need to explicitly deploy your web container. btw, default number of containers is 1 so you do not have to specify '--container' param.